# How to make a empty MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

What is wrong with the following syntax? This is the code that MySQL work bench made and I can't tell what is wrong with it.

```
CREATE TABLE `data1`.`table1` ();
```

Comment: You have to add the column descriptions.

Answer (score 10):

You are trying to create a table without columns. That is not possible in MySQL. You need to specify at least one column in order to create table.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing columns, a table need columns

Propper syntax would be:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
 id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 email VARCHAR(50),
 reg_date TIMESTAMP
 );
```

Read more about this at [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create_table.asp)

Answer (score 2):

A table is a collection of columns and rows. Without columns, it is not a table. '**An empty variable**'- would be the best name.
Check the `CREATE TABLE` syntax [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp).